# IE7 display issues (adding extra top margin)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am having a really tough time figuring out why IE7 adds extra padding to the this page!

This is what IE7 is doing:
http://imgur.com/lwyRI.png

The correct page would have the three black tabs connected to the graphic above.
This is how its supposed to look: also stored on imgur: 64qbf.png
(i am only allowed one link)

The page link can be found in the img. (again i can only post one link)

please help!

css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#background{
    background-image: url(/images/store/vaporIronBK.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:auto;
    width:665px;

    margin-top:125px;

    margin-left:228px;
    padding-top:5px;
    font-size:15px;
}

#background a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#background a:hover {
    color: #de156d;
}

#videoLinks  {
    margin-top:52px;
    height: 100px;
}

#buy{
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    padding-left:235px;
    color:#000000;
}

#video {
    float: right;
    left: 683px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 166px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #000000;
}

#video a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

#video a:hover {
    color: #de156d;
}

#footnotes  {
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-top: 37px;
}

#bottom-text {
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top:445px;
    width:575px;
}

#bottom-text a {
    color: #de156d;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#bottom-text a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

#bottom-text p {
    text-align: justify;
}

#bottom-text h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#bottom-text h3 {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#bottom-text p {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#bottom-text .header-text {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#bottom-text p.taylor-image {
    text-align: center;
}

.tabs {
    height: 30px;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you'll need to include some sample code/css/something. we can't debug from a static image...

Comment: Hard to tell without actually some code. How about adding at least the CSS/attribute definitions for that part of the page? Or are you using some WYSIWYG editor and don't know actual HTML/CSS?

Comment: post some html and css please. with this it will be like a fortune teller

Comment: What is the JS error? Would it have something to do with that?

Comment: it's ironic how his post about css needs some css adjustment...

Comment: sorry. I added the css from the page and you can we the live page here: http://www.joico.com/buy-appliances
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I do this to every page:

```
<body>
<!--[if IE]><div class="ie"><![endif]-->

...LALALA

<!--[if IE]></div><![endif]-->
</body>
```

It's called a conditional comment. It's IE proprietary, but acts like 
a comment to other browsers and validators.

Now you can specify IE specific rules using .ie ancestor.

get some .ie #whatever{position:relative;} going on and put those 
boxes where they're supposed to be!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this out in your CSS do

```
body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

alternatively would like to see some code as posted by others.

Comment: that is already added in the main css file. I also tried adding it to this page with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
display: inline;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok if you still cant find the solution, ie has a double margin bug, read about the css box model or for ease use a conditional like this:
this piece of code place in the head of the document,
and it will use this style sheet only when you are in the specified browser.
<!--[if IE7]> <link href="ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->

and add another style sheet just for the ie  that your having the problem with and remove the extra margin or whatever problems you are experiencing.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `margin-top:` from #background and instead add a `clear:both` or `clear:right` for #background.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, especially for IE7, but for better practice anyway, always specify all sides w/padding or margin...in other words don't just use margin-top:?px (? for whatever) and assume the rest is fine. Better to use margin:?px 0 0 0 or whatever values.

Another general idea, especially with IE 7 and below is to not use margin and padding on the same element.

Also, anything floated needs a width and as to the double-margin bug, it only occurs when you have margin on the same side as the side the element is floated.....so if you're declaring float:right on something, you don't want to have margin: 0 20px 0 0 on the same thing... it will get doubled. Better to use padding on the containing element.