# CSS Margin-top not working in IE7

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE7 display issues (adding extra top margin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475416/ie7-display-issues-adding-extra-top-margin)

So I have the following css

```
.socialMediaPlugin {
width: auto;
display: block;
.socialMediaPluginFooter {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: -12px;
```

}

And mark up

```
        <div class="socialMediaPlugin socialMediaPluginFooter">
      <div class="socialMediaLinks">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
        <a class="Pinterest"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And basically the     margin-top: 15px; in the socialMediaPluginFooter works fine in all browsers except for IE7 any ideas ?

Comment: Is the missing } for .socialMediaPlugin in your CSS a typo?

Comment: I don't see a difference between IE7 and IE8. Both don't show the margin like this, and both do with the typo corrected. So can you show some more code, preferably in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`margin-top` is very buggy in IE7. Use `padding-top` on the parent element.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/margin-top

Comment: And by `very buggy` I mean it doesn't work.

Comment: Just solved a very annoying problem thanks to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem may stem from your malformed css. Here's how it should be:

```
.socialMediaPlugin {
width: auto;
display: block;
}
.socialMediaPluginFooter {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: -12px;
}
```

Unless you've just mistyped it here, in which case it's another issue